# Swift detect touch in both left and right side of screen simultaneously

Tags: ios, swift, touches

I've been able to detect if the user is touching the left or right side of the screen and then perform a function. I'm trying to detect if both sides of the screen are being touched simultaneously and if so perform another function.

This is what I have which isn't working for when both sides of the screen are being touched at the same time.

This is in the update function.

```
if (touched) {
        var isRight : Bool = false
        var isLeft : Bool = false

        if(location.x < 0){
        isLeft = true
        moveLeft()
        }
        else if(location.x > 0){
        isRight = true
        moveRight()


            }
        else if (isRight && isLeft){
            moveUp()


        }

    }
```

Comment: For me? That's an extremely confusing touch action. (I'm guessing for a non-developer it's worse.) Can you explain what you want to detect this for? Personally I'd choose another gesture. But anyways, maybe you can use a pinch gesture to detect where each digit on a user's hand is? (Yes, I think this is a pretty poor design gesture.)

Comment: Basically touches left side of screen movesLeft... Touches right side of screen movesRight. Touches both left and right then fire object.

Comment: So this is a game touch? My two suggestions: (1) Like I said, try a pinch gesture (or go deeper with touchesBegan and touchesEnded - along with detecting two touches). (2) Put some kind of "layer" on each side. @Yitschak has an answer that may help.

Answer (score 1):

The following checks all the touches for touch side and builds a union value up as an integer value, which can then be checked with a switch statement:

```
struct Sides : OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int

    static let left = Sides(rawValue:1)
    static let right = Sides(rawValue:2)

    static let both : Sides = [.left, .right]
    static let none : Sides = []
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // Get sides touched
    let touched = touches.map { return $0.location(in: view) }.reduce(Sides.none) {
        if $1.x < 0 {
            return [ $0, Sides.left ]
        }
        else if $1.x > 0 {
            return [ $0, Sides.right ]
        }
        else {
            return $0
        }
    }

    switch(touched) {
    case Sides.left:
        // handle left
        break

    case Sides.right:
        // handle right
        break

    case Sides.both:
        // handle both
        break

    case Sides.none:
        fallthrough

    default:
        // none
        break

    }
}
```

Comment: I think `Sides` might be better implemented as an `OptionSet`. https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optionset

Comment: This is only returning "Right"?

Comment: True enough @BallpointBen, I couldn't come up with `OptionSet` at the time :)

Comment: @AlexIngram that's probably because I copied your left/right detection code which compares the location to zero.

Comment: What should it be compared to David? I've tried > self.frame.midX but no luck

Comment: In the map block apply whatever translation from location -> point you're currently using and then > 0/< 0 should continue to work.  I was working from less than complete information and really just trying to demonstrate collecting left/right/both hit information from what I had of your existing code.

Comment: I'm struggling to work out what to change I'm afraid David to get it how it was in my previous code.

Comment: Since I don't know what's outside the if-statement in your example code, there's really not much more I can offer.

Answer (score 0):

use this function to get an array of touch positions ant to test whether their position are (left and right)

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if touches.count == 2 {
        // 2 touches so we got 2 positions
        let tch_1 = touches[touches.startIndex].location(in: self.view)
        let tch_2 = touches[touches.endIndex].location(in: self.view)
        if (tch_1.x < self.view.frame.size.width / 2 && tch_2.x >= self.view.frame.size.width / 2) || (tch_2.x < self.view.frame.size.width / 2 && tch_1.x >= self.view.frame.size.width / 2) {
            //touch detected in both left and right side of screen simultaneously

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have time to write the code (I'm on the phone now - it will help if you post all the function). Basically you should get as parameter an array of touches. You than iterate through them and turn on flags: right/left side touched. And then you call your functions based on the flags

Comment: The function simply sending a sprite node from the player up to the top of the screen. So like firing a bullet upwards. I can't think of anyway to fire other than auto-shoot on a timer. I thought touches both sides would be a good way of doing this

Comment: I don't understand why -1. I wrote a great answer, (2 years ago!) just didn't write the code, but as I said, he gets an ARRAY of touches as a parameter, and that is the key to solution. Iterate them, and understand if he has only left, only right or both!!